# Exact match for words

Tags: python, regex

I would like to use regular expression that matches if a sentence contains one of the words that I am looking for.

All of these are matching now which is not correct. I used " " for all words in `words` (like `" seven "`) but this time it doesn't match if a word is at the end of the string.

```
words = ('seven', 'eight')
regex = re.compile('|'.join(words))
print regex.search('aaaaaasd seven asdfadsf')   #1 - should match
print regex.search('AAAsevenAAA')               #2 - shouldn't match
print regex.search('AAA eightaaa')              #3 - shouldn't match
print regex.search('eight aaa')                 #4 - should match
print regex.search('aaaa eight')                #5 - should match
```

How can I make that my regular expression doesn't match if matching word is one of the words' substring (like #2 and #3 above)?

Comment: enclose your words with word boundaries `\\bseven\\b` or with a raw string `r'\bseven\b'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @CasimiretHippolyte pointed out you want to add [**word boundaries**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-boundaries.html#wordboundary). If you don't want to manually do this for each word in your list, you need to modify your compiled regular expression.

```
regex = re.compile(r'\b(?:%s)\b' % '|'.join(words))
```

**Note:** If you have escape sequences in your regex, it's best to use raw string notation. By using a non-capturing `(?:...)` group, this allows your words to be grouped with word boundaries placed around them, otherwise it places a boundary at the very beginning and the very end.

[**Ideone Demo**](http://ideone.com/5oxS3j)

Comment: Hmm. I forgot to add _'r'_. That's why how much I tried it doesn't match.

Comment: Why do I need `?:`? Do you add that because you want to avoid grouping?

Comment: Yeah, that's what it does.

Comment: Can I ask one more question? I have words that starts with # and @ characters. This new regular expression doesn't match those. I think it's related to word boundary. Is there an easy way to include those?

Comment: What I try to ask this if a word starts with an not alphanumeric character (like `#unrushyourworld`) how can I make that regular expression matches with keeping the word boundaries. (In order words, it matches with ... `#unrushyourworld` but not `f#unrushyourworld`)

Comment: Sorry for consecutive comments but I think I found: `re.compile(r'(^|\s)(?:%s)($|\s)' % '|'.join(words_with_non_alphanumeric_characters)`