# How to I search a string for words with no spaces

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to find out how to read a string for names with no spaces
ex. robbybobby I want it to search the string and separate them into there own groups

```
def wordcount(filename, listwords):
    try:
        file = open(filename, "r")
        read = file.readline()
        file.close()
        for word in listwords:
            lower = word.lower()
            count = 0
            for letter in read:
                line = letter.split()
                for each in line:
                    line2 = each.lower()
                    line2 = line2.strip(".")
                    if lower == line2:
                        count += 1

            print(lower, ":", count)
    except FileExistsError:
        print("no")
wordcount("teststring.txt", ["robby"])
```

with this code it will only find robby if there is a space afterwards

Comment: Get it working just with a single string. Forget about the file. Concentrate on the essence of the problem. See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: `re.pattern('\w[a-zA-Z]*')`

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this. I am posting 2 suggestions so you can understand and improve :)

**Solution 1:**

```
def count_occurrences(line, word):
    # Normalize vars
    word = word.lower()
    line = line.lower()

    # Initialize vars
    start_index = 0
    total_count = 0
    word_len = len(word)

    # Count ignoring empty spaces
    while start_index >= 0:
        # Ignore if not found
        if word not in line[start_index:]:
            break

        # Search for the word starting from <start_index> index
        start_index = line.index(word, start_index)

        # Increment if found
        if start_index >= 0:
            start_index += word_len
            total_count += 1    

    # Return total occurrences
    return total_count

print(count_occurrences('stackoverflow overflow overflowABC over', 'overflow'))
```

Output: 3

**Solution 2:**

If you want to go for a regex, this links may be usefull:

1. [Count the occurrence of a word in a txt file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29465516/count-the-occurrence-of-a-word-in-a-txt-file-in-python)
2. [Exact match for words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29053902/exact-match-for-words)

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you want to count occurrences of a word irrespective to whether it occurs as a part of other word, or as a word on its own.

You can use simple regex for that:

```py
import re

def count_line(dict, line, words):
    for word in words:
        dict[word]=len(re.findall(word, line, re.IGNORECASE))+dict.get(word, 0)
    return dict

allLines="""
bobby robbubobby yo xyz\n
robson bobbyrobin abc\n
xyz bob amy oo\n
amybobson robson
"""

print(allLines)

words=["amy", "robby", "bobby", "jack"]
res={}
for line in allLines.split("\n"):
    res=count_line(res, line, words)
print(res)
```

Output:

```py
bobby robbubobby yo xyz

robson bobbyrobin abc

xyz bob amy oo

amybobson robson

{'amy': 2, 'robby': 0, 'bobby': 3, 'jack': 0}
```